# Is there a Youtube API endpoint to set sharing on a video within an organization?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an app that uploads private videos to Youtube to be viewed by everyone at our organization. Luckily, Google and Youtube have an awesome company-wide permission for this, which allows for anyone with an email address within the company to view these videos.

Youtube has 3 options for video privacy status: Public, Unlisted and Private. I'd usually just go with Unlisted and call it a day, but due to the nature of these videos, I'd prefer for them to Private, then manually grant access to the video and share it with everyone at the organization. When done through the Youtube Video Manager page, here is the dialog box I'm looking for an API endpoint for:

[image]

### Manual Approach

We can go through each video and check this box in each video, but that's not something that scales well. I'd love to find documentation on a Youtube API endpoint that handles this. There's a clear `status.privacyStatus` attribute for videos that can be set to `private`, `public` or `unlisted`, but nothing for this.

Does anyone know of a Youtube API andpoint to control this permission for private videos on Youtube?

Comment: Does your company use G Suite?

Comment: @paolo - Yes, good point -- that's what allows that option to show up. Others not part of an org won't be able to see this "share" option or modal at all.

Comment: Well, maybe not​ that exact modal, but you can definitely share private videos with other people manually, even without being part of an organization. Emphasis on manually, though. To my knowledge, the YouTube Data API v3 does not document such a feature, which is why I'm inclined to say it's not possible - at least with that particular API.

Comment: I just checked again, for other users the modal looks the same, except for the 'Let erveryone at ... view' checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

I can back up the assumption from my comment that private video sharing is not possible through the Data API v3 with [this article I found on the topic](http://stevezeidner.com/youtube-api-share-videos/).

The author of the article even provides a workaround to this problem, although I strongly discourage using it, since it requires parsing sensitive account information (password) in PHP. Apart from that, the code is from 2010 and will most likely not work anymore because it is from before YouTube channels were linked to Google+ pages.

Comment: Eek, yeah this article is trying to do the same thing as me for sure - aside form the "within an organization" part. Was scared I'd have to go down the web request route in order to do it, but at least it's nice to know that's the only way.

Comment: I just sincerely hope you're not going down that road. I'd rather click the box for every single video than use such a fishy script containing the password in plain text :D

Comment: Apart from that, you could try [filing a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600). But don't ask me if they listen to this, I have no idea...